# jQuery - interval not executed for the last slide - animation malfunction

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating a slider but using a bunch of divs instead of images. I have 3 divs in total, the first two can move pretty well, but the last one just flies away really fast - it shows for a moment and then moves back to the first div. I just want it to show the same amount of time as the first two. Here's my html code:

```
<div id="ibToShow">
    <div id='sliderWrapper'>
        <div class="infoBox" id="infob1">
            blablabla
        </div>

        <div class="infoBox" id="infob2">
            blablabla
        </div>

        <div class="infoBox" id="infob3">               
            blablabla
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's my jQuery code:

```
$(function () {
var width = '55vw';
var showTime = 2000;
var animationSpeed = 500;
var currentDiv = 1;

var $slider = $('#ibToShow');
var $sliderWrapper = $slider.find('#sliderWrapper');
var $infoBox = $sliderWrapper.find('.infoBox');

var interval;

function startSlider() {
    interval = setInterval(function () {
        $sliderWrapper.animate({'margin-left': '-=' + width}, animationSpeed, function(){
                currentDiv++;
            if (currentDiv === $infoBox.length){
                currentDiv = 1;
                $sliderWrapper.css('margin-left', 0);
            }
        })
    }, showTime);
}

function stopSlider() {
    clearInterval(interval);
}

$sliderWrapper.on('mouseenter', stopSlider).on('mouseleave', startSlider);

startSlider();
});
```

I sensed it might be because the animation stopped immediately after the third div showed up. But shouldn't it be waiting for what's set up in showTime?

This problem is still not fixed. Any takers?

Answer (score 0):

You are changing margin left to 0 right after the previous animation ends.
I think this would work better :

```
function startSlider() {
    interval = setInterval(function () {
        if(currentDiv++ <== $infoBox.length) {
            $sliderWrapper.animate({'margin-left': '-=' + width}, animationSpeed);
        }
        else {
            $sliderWrapper.animate({'margin-left': '0'}, animationSpeed);
            currentDiv = 0;
        }
    }, showTime);
}
```

Comment: The `===` should be replaced with `<`. And `currentDiv` reset to 1 instead of 0.